# Pyppeteer how to login on page with type

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, pyppeteer

I was using selenium + chrome driver for my python telegram bot deployed on linux server with docker.
Everything is working, but its not supporting async so my app can't do anything else during scraping.
I heard about Pyppeteer, but having some troubles with getting page i need to scrape.
Webpage requires me to login.
Here are steps:

1. Open page.
2. Click on auth button:

`<button class="btn btn-outline-warning kt-font-dark mr-2" type="button" id="btn_auth"> <i class="fa fa-key"></i> Enter </button>`

3. After logining div appears on page, and it has next 2 inputs:

`<input type="email" class="form-control pd-y-12" name="login[email]" placeholder="Email">`

`<input type="password" class="form-control pd-y-12" name="login[password]" placeholder="password">`

4. After inputing email and password, login button should be clicked.

`<button class="btn btn-warning btn-block mg-b-10" type="submit" name="do_login">login</button>`

Here i am trying to do:

```
    async def main(url):
        browser = await launch(headless=False)
        page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.goto(url)
        await asyncio.gather(
            page.waitForSelector('button[class="btn btn-outline-warning kt-font-dark mr-2"]', timeout=60000),
            page.click('button[class="btn btn-outline-warning kt-font-dark mr-2"]'),
            page.waitForSelector('button[class="btn btn-warning btn-block mg-b-10"]', timeout=60000),
            page.type('[type=email]', 'example@gmail.com'),
            page.type('[type=password]', 'example'),
            page.click('button[class="btn btn-warning btn-block mg-b-10"]')
        )
        await browser.close()
        return
```

Right now can find and click first button, input doesnt work. Also need to return page HTML content

Comment: Maybe you need to scroll down first to your input tag/